# problem with gicp in rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there. i managed to get rgbdslam running with both gicp_code and gicp_bin. the problem is, when using gicp_code, the program runs for some time (about 3 or 4 seconds) and then it shuts down. when i use gicp_bin, after i hit the space bar, i get  Non-zero return value from ./gicp/test_gicp... Identity transformation is returned instead of GICP result... sh: ./gicp/test_gicp: not found. could anybody figure out why?
i'm using the rgbdslam checked from openslam.org.
My CPU is i5, 4G memory. Ubuntu 10.04

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12472/problem-with-gicp-in-rgbdslam/) by [yayafree186](https://answers.ros.org/users/1578/yayafree186/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, we hadn't touched the GICP code for a while, since it didn't improve our results. Since we didn't test it anymore changes elsewhere broke the GICP functionality. I fixed that and will properly release a new version as soon as my work schedule permits. Try updating your svn in a few days.

However, in my experiments with GICP, SIFTGPU and SURF the results with Features+GICP are still slightly worse than Features only. Depends on the scenario of course.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0